# Forge Viewer Navigation Extension

Tags: java, autodesk-forge, autodesk, forge, autodesk-viewer

I am following this tutorial but I want to achieve something slightly different:
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/extensions/

I want to lock the navigation and only enable the feature to rotate left and right (or 360 degrees) - horizontally - keeping the model centered in an absolute position on the screen.

Would this be possible?

Comment: Sorry, we don't yet have an API to control the rotation

Comment: Oh, that's strange... because if I am using the arrows (left/right), the model is navigation just like I want it to do. The only difference is that I want it automatically to rotate. Edit: seems like the function already exsist: https://viewer-rocks.autodesk.io/ (click the rotate in the toolbar). How does he do it?

Comment: the feature on viewer-rocks is auto-rotating the mode, but a user still can rotate in any direction. I understood your question as: how to allow one left/right rotation of the model. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Yes you are correct. I was thinking that maybe it was possible to set the model to autorotate and deactivate navigation. Meaning that the model will rotate and it will not be possible to interface with the rotating navigation. If you understand where I'm heading. Sorry for being vague and thanks for helping!

Comment: have you looked at the viewer-rocks source code? more specifically at this function https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-react-express-headless/blob/master/src/components/Viewer/Viewer-helpers.js#L241